# how to add an auto Increment to a table which has composite key means two primary keys

Tags: mysql

I have two primary keys in one table. First one is `PropertyID` and second one is `ImageID`. I want to to add an auto increment with starting = 1000 to the `PropertyID`. I tried to use the command below, but get this error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000' at line 3`

Here is the command:

```
Alter Table Properties
Alter Column `PropertyID` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;
```

Comment: If you are using an auto-incremented column then it is guaranteed to be unique so why would you use a composite primary key?

Comment: read my post i m using composite key but i want one of them to be AUTO INCREMETN

Comment: I did read your post.  Read my comment.  **WHY** are you using a composite key if one of them is an auto-increment?  It is **POINTLESS** to do so.

Comment: What is the schema definition for the table? Are both `ProertyID` and `ImageID` integers or strings? If the latter, you can't do what you want to do. Am I correct in assuming that the values for these two fields come from separate, related tables? If so, just add a single field which is auto-increment and add separate indexes for `PropertyID` and `ImageID` and not a composite

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add ALTER COLUMN

```
ALTER TABLE `Properties` AUTO_INCREMENT =1000
```

Comment: its executing an empty query.